# Recursive for For loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a scenario to get a output like the following.

```
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 0
0 1 1
1 0 0
1 0 1
1 1 0
1 1 1
```

When the input is 3 it would give 8 combinations as above. If the input is 4, there would be 16 combinations. I am able to achieve this using nested for loop as below.

```
value1 = 2, value2 = 2, value3 = 2;
my function () {
    for(var i = 0; i<this.value1; i++) { 
      for(var j = 0; j < this.value2; j++) { 
        for(var k = 0; k < this.value3; k++) { 
           console.log(i,j,k);
        }
      }
    }
}
```

This is fine if it is for input 3, But I have to get the output for input 10. So I need to write 10 nested for loops as above. I know it is bad practice, I don't know how to use the recursive here. Please help me on this.

Comment: Use an array. Increment the current element of the array, when it reaches the maximum value wrap it around to 0 and then do the same for the next element.

Comment: `Array(Math.pow(2,4)).fill(0).forEach((_,i) => console.log(i.toString(2)));` *almost* produces the desired output for the input 4. This approach could be tweaked to give the exact output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a recursive function that can do the required job.

```js
function solveUtil(limits, index, cur) {
    if (index === limits.length) {
        console.log(cur.join(' '));
    } else {

        for (let i = 0; i < limits[index]; i++) {
            cur.push(i);
            solveUtil(limits, index + 1, cur);
            cur.pop();
        }
    }
}

function solve(limits) {
    solveUtil(limits, 0, []);
}

solve(new Array(10).fill(2));
```

Answer (score 2):

The recursive approach would look something like this:

```
function recursive(n, range, prefix) {
  prefix = prefix || "";
  if (n == 0)
    console.log(prefix);
  else
    for (let i = 0; i < range; i++)
      recursive(n - 1, range, prefix + " " + i);
}

recursive(10, 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take advantage of the fact you're looking for combinations in binary and just simply count from 0 in binary and add padding.

This uses [function generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*), but it's easy to convert it to a simple function.

```js
function * findCombinations(n){
  for(let i = 0; i < Math.pow(2, n); i++){
    const c = i.toString(2);
    const padding = new Array(n - c.length + 1).join('0');
    yield padding + c;
  }
  return null;
}

const iterator = findCombinations(4);
console.log(
  Array.from(iterator)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In newer browsers (which support [.padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)), the following produces the desired output (but bypasses rather than solves the problem with recursion):

```js
let n = 4; //or any other value
    
Array(Math.pow(2,n)).fill(0).forEach((_,i) => console.log(i.toString(2).padStart(n,'0').split('').join(' ')));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`Generator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) with [`function*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) and take the combination on the fly.

```js
function* binary(length, array = []) {
    if (--length) {
        yield* binary(length, [...array, 0]);
        yield* binary(length, [...array, 1]);
    } else {
        yield [...array, 0];
        yield [...array, 1];
    }
}

[...binary(3)].map(a => console.log(...a));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```